# Suspend app option

Tags: iphone

I have an app that i have and I have it set to NOT run in background but a number people want to option to have it resume from where they left off and a number of people just want it to start from the beginning when they tap the home button and restart to app.  How do I add an on/off switch to give the user the option?   My app is a educational / reference app with flashcards and pdfs.

Thanks

J

Comment: Add a option to the apps settings (i.e. store current state), check that option and implement accordingly?

Comment: You can have an option that will store all of the app's data in a file that can be loaded to bring the user back to where they left off.

Answer (score 0):

Create a settings bundle as described [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html).

Add your setting as a boolean value.  Have it default to the way most people will use your app.

Now at launch read the value of the setting and act accordingly.  The setting will appear in the System Preferences app under your app's name.

Comment: I added the bundle just like its listed in the example you have above but that refers to locking the rotation not to running in background.  Any references would be great.

Comment: I meant use that as a guide to creating your own setting, like "Run in Background" as a boolean.  Then you can use that setting to determine if the user wants to run in the background.